# Pandas Python: sort df while excluding given rows by label

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, splice

I have a df which looks like this:

```
Name           UnweightedBase    Base    exp1
Name                                         
UnweightedBase           1046    1046    1046
Base                     1046    1046    1046
ppola1                     15   1,28%   1,28%
ppola2                      9   1,21%   1,21%
ppola3                     10   1,07%   1,07%
ppola4                     46   5,32%   5,32%
ppola5                    171  16,91%  16,91%
ppola6                     36   4,01%   4,01%
ppola7                     45   3,88%   3,88%
ppola8                     28   2,63%   2,63%
ppola9                      4   0,29%   0,29%
ppola10                   178  17,76%  17,76%
```

I want to build 2 seprate sub dfs based on a list of index labels. 1 which includes the labels and 1 which doesn't

Heres the list I want to check against:

```
fixedlist = ["ppola8", "ppola9", "ppola10"]
```

my attempts to create these sub dfs:

```
1) included = df_raw.loc[exclude_list]
2) excluded = df_raw.loc[~exclude_list]
```

the 1st "included" df works but the 2nd doesnt, I get the following error:

```
TypeError: bad operand type for unary ~: 'list'
```

How do I get around this?

Comment: does this work `excluded = df_raw[~df_raw.index.isin(exclude_list)]`?

Comment: That does indeed. I can see where I went wrong now, thanks Ed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do what you attempted like that hence the error because the unary operator won't work on a list.

You can achieve what you want by doing

```
excluded = df_raw[~df_raw.index.isin(exclude_list)]
```

the inner statement will produce a boolean index that can be used to index your df.